# Moving a shape in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to move a shape in javafx using the arrows keys but I cannot get it work.

I have a separate class for the shape, but cannot get the translations to show up. The shape isnt even appearing at the right coordinates set in the constructor.

Im really not sure what Im doing wrong and would appreciate any input.

Class: `Moon_master`
    public class Moon_master extends Application {

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        hero p1 = new hero();

        p1.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP){               
                p1.moveUp();


            } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN){
                p1.moveDown();

            }
        });       

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(p1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        p1.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Class: `hero`

```
/*
 * @author jack
 */
public class hero extends StackPane {

    Rectangle body = new Rectangle(200,125,50,50);
    double newX , newY;

    public hero () {
       getChildren().add(body);
    }

    public void moveUp(){
        newY = body.getY() - 6;
        body.setY(newX);          
    }

    public void moveDown(){
        newY = body.getY() + 6;
        body.setY(newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: First  I think your function moveUp() should be "body.setY(newY)" instead of newX

Comment: And try adding the focus to the root Node instead of having it on the Hero. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734989/how-to-change-the-start-and-end-point-of-line-using-arrow-keys-in-javafx/35737412#35737412

Comment: I looked at the link you posted and made those changes, but it still isnt working. Does it have something to do with my hero class?

Answer (score 3):

After making the fixes already mentioned in the comments make the hero
a simple Pane instead of a StackPane.

```
public class hero extends Pane {
```

StackPane is a layout pane which is constantly fighting agains your manual placement of your hero.